# Spearfishing in Greece

Tags: greece

I am curious to know about the spearfishing regulations in Greece, especially if there are any locations/areas where it's allowed.

I saw there's a [similar question from 2017](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/92004/what-are-the-spearfishing-freediving-regulations-in-greece), but as far as I know the laws have changed since then and for example licenses are no longer required.

I usually go couple of times during the summer in the Chalkidiki area, during the day, with bouy in non-chowder places, but last year a local told me that spearfishing is not allowed in Nea Kalikrateia/Nea Moudania area. So I presume if there are restrictions they should be described somewhere

Comment: The usual way here is to get the older question and answers updated, not to ask a new question. You can 'rescue' this question if you edit it to be about the specific location and ask for the restrictions there.

Comment: This is not enough of an edit, it is still a duplicate of the previous question, but thanks for the link.

Comment: @Willeke thanks a lot for your +100 bounty on the other question :)